# Calculate the character degrees of a finite group $G$.

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ be a group of order $8$. Suppose that $G/K\cong M_{12}$ where $M_{12}$ is one of the Mathieu group.

QUESTION:

How to calculate the all complex character degrees of $G$?

Comment: What can you deduce about the extension of $K$ by $M_{12}$? Can it be non-split?